# Cocoapods: Pod is in the master repo but is not available for install

Tags: ios, macos, cocoapods, podspec

I've created and submitted a podspec, [BCJSONMapper](https://github.com/benedictC/BCJSONMapper), but when I search for it using `pod search BCJSONMapper` I receive the following error: `[!] Unable to find a pod with name matching 'BCJSONMapper'`.

The [spec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/BCJSONMapper/0.0.2/BCJSONMapper.podspec.json) is in the master repo (it was submitted via trunk). I can use the pod as expected if I refer to a local copy of the podspec in a podfile (`pod 'BCJSONMapper', :podspec => '~/path/to/local/copy/of/BCJSONMapper.podspec'`).

How do I fix this? This is the first podspec that I've submitted to the master repo so I may have missed something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it. I solved it by removing my `~/.cocoapods/repos/master` and letting Cocoapods re-initalize the repo. What was confusing was that the same error message was occurring on a different machine. It may have just been coincidence, but I guess it could also have been a bug in Cocoapods.